# Question about fixed point of a convex function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, convex-analysis

Let me define
$\textbf{Definition 1}$: A mapping $\Phi:\mathbb{R^+}\to\mathbb{R^+}$ is said to be an N function

Answer (score 1):

Of course $0$ is one fixed point.  The second one exists by the Intermediate Value Theorem because (4) implies $\Phi(x) < x$ for $x$ near $0$ and (5) implies $\Phi(x) > x$ for large $x$.  There are only two because of convexity: if $\Phi(x_1) < x_1$ and $\Phi(x_2) = x_2$, $0 < x_1 < x_2$, then for $x > x_2$ convexity implies
$\Phi(x) > x$.

Comment: @jeniffer Yes, because $\Phi(x) \ge 0$ there can be no negative fixed points.