# Is the following proof about the Nice Young functions (a type of convex function) true?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convex-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, convex-geometry

Let me define the N-functions first,
**Definition 1:** A mapping $\Phi:\mathbb{R^+}\to\mathbb{R^+}$ is said to be an N function if
(1) $\Phi$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R^+}$
(2) $\Phi$ is convex
(3) $\Phi(x)=0$ iff $x=0$
(4) $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\Phi(x)}{x}=0$
(5) $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\Phi(x)}{x}=\infty$

$\textbf{1.}$ Let $\Phi:\mathbb{R^+}\to\mathbb{R^+}$ be an N-function, then it will have exactly one fixed point other than zero.

$\textbf{Proof:}$
Since $\Phi$ is an N-function then by definition, $0$ is a fixed point of $\Phi$.
To show that there exists exactly one $0\neq x\in \mathbb{R^+}$ such that $\Phi(x)=x$
$\textbf{Existence:}$ Since $\Phi$ is N-function so $lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\Phi(x)}{x}=0$ implies $\exists \hspace{0.2cm} x_1\in \mathbb{R^+}$ such that $\Phi(x)<x$ $\forall x\leq x_1$ similarly since $lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\Phi(x)}{x}=\infty$ implies $\exists$ $\hspace{0.2cm}$ $x_2\in \mathbb{R^+}$ such that $\Phi(x)>x \forall x\geq x_2$
$$\mbox{ Let } g(x)=\Phi(x)-x \mbox{ where } x\in[x_1,x_2]$$
since $\Phi(x)$ and $x$ are continuous then $g(x)$ is also continuous.
$$g(x_1)=\Phi(x_1)-x_1<0 \mbox{ and } g(x_2)=\Phi(x_2)-x_2>0$$
hence by intermediate value theorem there exists $c\in[x_1,x_2]$ such that $g(c)=0$ implies $\Phi(c)=c$
$\textbf{Uniqueness:}$ If $\Phi(x_1)<x_1$ and $\Phi(x_2)=x_2$,$0<x_1<x_2$ then for $x>x_2$ convexity implies $\Phi(x)>x$ hence there is only one fixed point.

Here I have proved that the N functions has exactly two fixed points including $0$,I just wanted to know is my proof is correct,please if someone help if there is any mistake that will be great help.Thanks.

Comment: Btw: I noticed that you got answers for many of your questions, but never *accepted* an answer so far. If you are not aware of it: Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/196432) for more information.

Comment: okay,actually I was not aware of this,Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: How is this question different from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4532794/42969 ? It seems that what you wrote for the uniqueness part is essentially what you got as an answer to your older question.

Comment: what about existence part?

Comment: was also answered in the other question.